# What is the c# equivalent of public final static in java

Tags: c#, java, static, final, public

In Java I can write:

```
public final static MyClass foo = new MyClass("foo");
```

Is there any equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The closest thing (not exactly the same, [`final` has other meanings](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/final-keyword.shtml) too) for Java `final` fields I can think of is [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(VS.71).aspx):

```
public static readonly MyClass field = new MyClass("foo");
```

If you have a primitive type (string, int, boolean), you may want to use `const` instead.

```
public const string MAGIC_STRING = "Foo";
```

Comment: For fields, they're *almost* exactly the same thing. There are different rules around initialization (irrelevant here) and for some times `final` fields in Java act like `const` fields in C#, but in this case I think they're effectively equivalent.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between `readonly` and `const` though. `const` bakes in the value, so if you swap out a DLL with a `const` value in it, other DLLs consuming that one will need a rebuild to get the new value. `readonly` is runtime and will not require this.

Comment: So we don't need "static" for the primitive type?

Answer (score -5):

```
sealed class finalClass
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's for a *class* - this is a *field*.